# For $x+y+z=0$, if $x$ and $y$ are divisible by some integer $k$, then so is $z$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $k|x$ and $k|y$ and $x+y+z = 0$, then $k|z$. Here, "$k|x$" means that $k$ is a divisor of $x$ and $x,y,z,k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

What strategy would you employ to prove this?

Comment: When you use /, is that to be read "divides"? And, do you mean z instead of c?

Comment: yes "/" is to be read "divides" and yes, I did mean z, thank you

Comment: @user3308043 (You should use a vertical line for divides: "|" It's usually the same key as backslash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k|x$ and $k|y$, so we know that:

1) There's some integer $a$ where $\ k\cdot a = x$

2) There's some integer $b$ where $\ k\cdot b=y$.

Then by adding the two equations, $k\cdot a + k\cdot b=k\cdot(a+b)=x+y$.

$(a+b)$ is an integer so $k|(x+y)$.

But $x+y=-z$, so $k|(-z)$ so k divides integer multiples of $-z$ (in particular, $-1\cdot -z$), so $k|z$.

Comment: What does `|` mean here?

Comment: `|` is meant to be read as 'divides'

Comment: This is just a request, if you could, would you be able to break down your first line for easier readability (for the mind, not the eyes)?

Comment: Sure thing....!

Comment: excellent, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$k | x \Rightarrow x = kq$ for some $q \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $k | y \Rightarrow y = kp$ for some $p \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore $\displaystyle\frac{x + y + z}{k} = \displaystyle\frac{x}{k} + \displaystyle\frac{y}{k} + \displaystyle\frac{z}{k} = 0$ implies $\displaystyle\frac{z}{k} = - (q + p)$, so $k | z$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ \ \ z\ =\ -\overbrace{x}^{\large k\,a} -\overbrace{y}^{\large k\,b}\ =\ k\,(-a-b)\,\Rightarrow\, k\mid z $

**Or:** $\ \ {\rm mod}\ k\!:\ \ x\equiv 0\equiv y\ \Rightarrow\ 0 \equiv x+y+x\equiv z$